# blocked IP for connect through FTP

Tags: ftp, cpanel, web-hosting

I work for my apps in remote server with aptana editor. but suddenly when I am trying to connect through FTP, I got an error that my IP blocked. But I can connect direct to cpanel through my domain name with same IP. Please help me to unblock my IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. If your IP is blocked on your server then you can not login your cPanel, FTP and mail accounts.  Can you please let me know what exact error are you getting in FTP prompt.